# Implementing password reset with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I was reading an article on passport.js and I stumbled upon this piece of code and I dont know what it does the article does not do a good job in explaining it. Can you please explain what it does?

```
app.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'SendGrid',
        auth: {
          user: '!!! YOUR SENDGRID USERNAME !!!',
          pass: '!!! YOUR SENDGRID PASSWORD !!!'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot');
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code to explain. Exactly what parts of the code do you not understand?

Comment: From `async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });`

Comment: For reference, here is the entire blog post: http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is attempting to initialize a password reset type thing from a webapp -- although since we can't see the other relevant code, there's no way to know whether or not this is safe to use.

From your other responses, it looks as if you're confused about the `async.waterfall` and `crypto.randomBytes` stuff, so I'll attempt to explain those here.

`async.waterfall` is a helper function in the popular [asyncjs](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) library. It basically works by letting you specify a series of functions that will be run one after the other, passing the output of each one into the next function to be run.

`crypto.randomBytes` is essentially an easy way to generate a random string of characters. It's generating a random string (token) that will be used to generate a link to a 'secure' password reset page in an email to the user, something like:

https://www.example.com/reset_password?token=randomstringhere

This way, when the user clicks that link, you can verify that it is at most a certain amount of time OLD, and guarantee that it has never been reset before.